# Plugging in to Proxmox server directly

Tags: networking, webserver, proxmox

I just ordered a Lenovo ThinkCentre M900 Tiny to do some homeserver stuff. Its my first encounter with this kind of software. As we are in the summer holiday i live like a nomad, switching between different houses.
I would like to be able to connect my M2 macbook pro trough a Ugreen usb hub directly to the Lenovo ThinkCentre with an ethernet cable and be able to connect to Proxmox over that link.

How do i set this up, do i need to set a static IP on the nic of my hub, or what ip should i set on my Proxmox server.

Can anyone help me out
Thnx!

Comment: Try setting the server to static `10.0.0.1` and PC to `10.0.0.2`? If your PC has another interface like wifi for internet connection, just make sure it's not also using 10.X (usually like `192.168.0.123`), and it should work fine.